# Divi: Sections in desktop view suddenly disappearing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi-theme

I'm currently working on a page using Divi. I have a tablet and mobile views and currently I'm experiencing may be a bug in Divi. I am using Visibility to enable and disable sections on desktop, tablet, and mobile views. My problem is my desktop sections suddenly disappeared in my desktop view however they are working perfectly fine on desktop.

I've already tried double-checking the Visibility settings but they are ticked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
My problem is my desktop sections suddenly disappeared in my desktop view however they are working perfectly fine on desktop.
```

Try updating the Divi theme and see if the problem still exists. If this doesn't work, try the following steps.

1. Go to Divi Support Center menu in the Wordpress admin panel and check the System Status for any Server, memory, space-related issues.
2. Enable Safe Mode and deactivate the plugins to check whether there is any plugin conflict. (By enabling the Safe mode, Deactivating the plugins won't reflect for the website users, this is for debugging purpose only).

I faced a similar issue. I solved it by enabling the Safe mode and it was a plugin conflict in my case.